# Why can === have some odd behavior in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm raising the question as seen from [this Code Academy lesson](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/programming-intro/5#!/exercises/4). Thanks in advance for your explanations.

Hope this is not repeated too often.

-------- Explanation from the lesson is added below ----------------

> You may have noticed we've used two types of equals thus far, the single equals (=) and the double or triple equals (==, ===). The single equals (=) assigns a variable, while the double and triple equals (==, ===) are used to check equivalence between values. Since == can have some odd behavior in JavaScript, it is almost always better to use ===.
>
> Run this exercise to see what it does. It first sets the variable word to the string "this". Change the code so that word === "that" evaluates to true, and the console.log() command is run.

Comment: Would you care to post the question here?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I thought the question was evident in the title.

Comment: Hitting the run button the link you provided just generates an "Oops, try again" message. Pretty sure a tiny bit of research would help you here.

Comment: The "oops try again" is just some sort of bug in their page.  It has nothing to do with the technical behavior of `==` or `===`.

Comment: The error has to do with what the user types in the editor window.

Comment: What odd behavior are you asking about?  The question here is obviously not clear to many of us and all you say is "you thought it was evident in the title" and don't offer any clarification.  Either you want us to help you or not.  If you want help, please make the question a lot more obvious!

Comment: I think you mean `==` can have odd behavior, not `===`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The triple equals `===` returns true if both operands are the same type and have the same value.

The double equals `==` returns true if both operands can be coerced to the same type (following a specific set of rules) and have the same value after being coerced.

So, some examples:

```
1 === 1       // true
1 === "1"     // false
1 == 1        // true
1 == "1"      // true
"5" == 2 + 3  // true
0 == ""       // true
0 === ""      // false
null == undefined      // true
null === undefined     // false
```

Answer (score 4):

The only cases I know of `===` having "odd behavior" is when the *native-value* (e.g. `string`) is compared against an *object-value* (e.g. `String`) that "is convertible to" the native value:

```
"a" === "a"                         // true
"a" == new String("a")              // true
"a" === new String("a")             // false- uh, what?
new String("a") == new String("a")  // false- thought it was gonna be true? :)
new String("a") === new String("a") // false
var a = new String("a"); a === a    // true
```

The same holds for the other wrapper types, such as `Number`. This is because, when using `===`, JavaScript uses a different algorithm that does not perform coercions.

There have been some interesting browser bugs in the past where certain methods, say in `String.prototype`, would return a `String` and not a `string` causing code to break in subtle ways.

As others have pointed out, the behavior of `==` is often more ... interesting. I *almost exclusively* find that `==` Does The Right Thing™ , but understanding the details is important to mastering JavaScript.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

If two variables contain the same value but are not of the same type, == "forces" the equality and return true. However, === will return false, as it requires that two variables have the same value *and* be of the same tye in order to be equal. Otherwise, they behave similarily.

Comment: == can "force" equality between two variables of different types containing the same value? Does that mean I can compare variables of different types robustly in javascript using ===?

Comment: Yes, so if you want to be strict, I'd recommend ===, and if not, ==.

Answer (score 3):

`==` checks if the values are equivalent. `===` checks if the values are identical.

To illustrate this example, take a look at this:

```
"1" == 1 // this is TRUE, because the values are equivalent.
"1" === 1 // this is FALSE, because the values are of different types.
```

I have yet to encounter a case where I need `===` in JavaScript, because it is a relatively recent addition to the language, so for example `indexOf` returns a negative number to mean "no match" (whereas PHP returns `false` so you have to use `===` to differentiate between "no match" and "match at start of string").

Comment: "Relatively recent"? I admit I can't give a date for when it was introduced, but it's been around for a decade at least.

Comment: I have no idea when it was added, but it most definitely wasn't around in JavaScript 1.3. Still, can anyone give an example of when `===` is required?

Comment: That could be another question that I can ask the community (in the context of which version was === introduced). Thanks! Cheers!

Comment: They definitely were in JavaScript 1.3 (or ECMAScript 262 3rd edition from '99). As for when `===` is required, if you want to test whether a variable is `null` is the first example that comes to mind: if you use `==` then you can't tell the difference between `null` and `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

I would **highly** recommend you watch this presentation by [Bucky Schwarz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92446/hooray-im-helping):

- http://textiles.online.ncsu.edu/online/SilverlightPlayer/Default.aspx?peid=b2e41bcc02cc4a169a0baaa4ecb960ac1d

Within the first 5 minutes he talks about this topic.

Taken from one of his slides:

```
'' == '0' // false
 0 == ''  // true
 0 == '0' // true

false == 'false' // false
false == '0'     // true
false == 0       // true

false == undefined // false
false == null      // false
null  == undefined // true
```